# When passing the valid url of the string with the init the URL(string: urlString) returns nil. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

When passing the valid url of the string with the init the URL(string: urlString) returns nil. How to fix? When I enter a value from one word (for example, Moscow) everything works, when a city from two words is entered, I separate the request using split(separator: " ") and connect using .joined(separator: "%20") and get the city divided by %20 and return nil. How can this problem be solved?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH1Ju.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXQfV.jpg)

Comment: Please reformat your code, instead of pictures paste code directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `addingPercentEncoding` see my extension for that

```
extension String {
    var url: URL? {
        guard !isEmpty else { return nil }

        if let url = URL(string: self) {
            return url
        } else if let urlEscapedString = addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
                 let escapedURL = URL(string: urlEscapedString) {
            return escapedURL
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the apiKey after encoding it:

```swift
let encodedKey = key.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: Not working. I try see my URL object
(https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=<MYKEY>&q=New%20York)
If set this link in a browser, I can use data, but if I try use this link in my app, I can't get datas, I get error